# SQL Query for getting available locations within 2 dates in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with locations and the dates when they are occupied in Access mdb database.

```
   CREATE TABLE `locations`  (
  `LocationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `StartDate` date NOT NULL,
  `EndDate` date NULL DEFAULT NULL
) 


INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (1, 'Venue A', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-10');
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (2, 'Venue B', '2023-10-15', '2023-10-20');
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (3, 'Venue C', '2023-10-05', '2023-10-12');
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (4, 'Venue D', '2023-10-08', NULL);
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (5, 'Venue E', '2023-10-25', NULL);
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (6, 'Venue F', '2023-10-21', '2023-10-25');
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (7, 'Venue G', '2023-10-30', '2023-11-05');
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (8, 'Venue H', '2023-11-01', '2023-11-10');
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (9, 'Venue I', '2023-11-15', NULL);
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (10, 'Venue J', '2023-12-01', '2023-12-05');
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (11, 'Venue K', '2023-12-10', '2023-12-20');
INSERT INTO `locations` VALUES (12, 'Venue L', '2023-12-15', NULL);
```

What would be the query to get locations that are free between 2 dates.
For example, from '2023-10-21' and '2023-11-20' the result would be:

| Location |
| --- |
| Venue A |
| Venue B |
| Venue C |
| Venue J |
| Venue K |
| Venue L |

Comment: Is each venue listed just once. Or can you have a venue listed multiple times with different dates?

Comment: @Zack each venue can be listed multiple times with different dates

Comment: Do you have a table of all locations where each location is unique record? Maybe: `SELECT * FROM LocationsLookup WHERE LocID NOT IN(SELECT LocationID FROM Locations WHERE (StartDate BETWEEN #2023-10-21# AND #2023-11-20#) OR (EndDate BETWEEN #2023-10-21# AND #2023-11-20#)`.

Comment: @June7 Yes I have a separate table with only locations (or Venues), but I wanted to simplify the question as much as possible so I put only one table and put the locations (venues) as a regular varchar

Comment: I don't think my suggestion has correct criteria but hopefully you get the point. Subquery returns all locations that are committed for specified period and outer query returns venues that are not in nested dataset. I will have to do some testing on criteria to figure out correct structure.

Comment: @June7: but then your going to miss cases where the venue is booked e.g. between `2023-09-01` and `2023-12-01`.

Comment: Why are D, E, I eliminated? Unknown end, not just 1 day? Some date value will have to be supplied for Null.

Comment: @June7 yes, D,E,I have a starting date, but no ending date. So they are occupied forever from the start date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @June7's approach, but using an `EXISTS` clause, and a bit simplified logic:

```
SELECT * FROM venues
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM locations 
    WHERE 
        LocationID = venues.VenueID
        AND StartDate <= #11/20/23#
        AND NZ(EndDate, #10/21/23#) >= #10/21/23#
)
```

This replicates what you'd have to do if checking manually: For a given venue, check the location dates to see if there's an entry within the date range you're searching for (i.e., show me those venues/locations for which there doesn't exist an entry with a date range overlapping your dates).

As @June7 alluded to, you can use parameters, which would improve the readability and extensibility of the query in some respects, but using form controls might be better in some ways too. For example:

```
PARAMETERs pStartDate DATE, pEndDate Date;

SELECT * FROM venues
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM locations 
    WHERE 
        LocationID = venues.VenueID
        AND StartDate <= pEndDate
        AND NZ(EndDate, pStartDate) >= pStartDate
)
```

Comment: That is the answer, thanks Zack. Just some clarifications. On track of @June7 comment.  We need to create the venues table (SELECT DISTINCT locations.Location INTO venues
FROM locations;) and I changed the LocationID to Location in your where (Location = venues.Location)